# static django not calling media files

Tags: django

All files in static folder are served like css, font..etc.. but files in media folder aren't like images

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static('media/', document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static('static/', document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

html

```
<img src='{% static 'media/item/{{data[i].item_photo}}' %}'>
```

The image in file can be accessed and displayed using the link
http://localhost:8000/media/item/cake2_Iq0qS8s.jpeg

The error says the path is incorrect when i run html
http://localhost:8000/static/media/item/%7B%7Bdata%5Bi%5D.item_photo%7D%7D (404 not found)

My question is how to call image in media folder using static?

Comment: Turns out i should just use <img src='data[i].item_photo''>

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the image url incorrectly

```
<img src='{{ data[i].item_photo.url }}'>
```

Comment: Still not working, the error "Could not parse the remainder"